# How to deal with historical tables in ORM?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I have a historical data in different tables splitted by year: mydata_2008, mydata_2009, mydata_2010, mydata_2011, mydata_2012 and live data in mydata table.

I want to have only a mydata.cfc model that looks first in mydata table and if there are not data in it, continues searching in the historical tables.

Can be this done with ColdFusion ORM (hibernate) ?

Comment: The second paragraph of Scott Stroz's answer has very good advice.  You should follow it.

Comment: David, you didn't specify which database system you're using. That info might be relevant to what options make sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ColdFusion, an ORM object can only be related to a single table. However, you could over ride the `getter` for any given property to search the other tables when no data exists in the current year. This is not ideal as every year you will need to update the table the object is related to.

I suggest that you NOT split out your data based on year and keep it all in one table but add a `year` column so that you can differentiate data from different years. This will make managing the ORM object and getting 'historical' data much easier.

Comment: Add a year column _and a year index_ - the reason for splitting tables is probably performance; so making sure there is a suitable index is important to not degrading that.

Comment: Good point. I had thought to mention an index when I started preparing my answer and forgot.

Comment: Alternatively, if the data has a date field you might not need a year field.

Comment: Hmm, would be curious to know whether there's a significant difference in doing `year != year(now)` vs `date >= now-dayofyear(now)` - it feels like a not equals should be simpler/faster, but I've nothing to back that up with, and I guess it could depends on DBMS.

Comment: Thanks for response scott. The DB is a legacy SQLServer database so for the moment I can not join the tables in one, so I must go to the override getter way. How can I do this in a clean way?